# How mant times is 'too many times' to fill a TableAdapter before finding another way to acheive what i want?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tableadapter

I have a form where users can assign serial numbers to locations. The location is selected from a list of locations which is a `DataGridView` bound to `tblLocations` in my `DataSet` via `tblLocationsBindingSource`.

I have a second `DataGridView` displaying the serial numbers scanned against that location which is bound to `tblSerialNumbers` in my `DataSet` via `tblSerialNumbersBindingSource`, it is filled by `fkLocation` = @LocationID.

When a user scans a serial number it updates the rows `fkLocation` in `tblSerialNumbers` and i then re fill the `tblSerialNumbersTableAdapter` to update the `DataGridView`.

I wondered if this is bad practice? as there could be anywhere between 50-100 serials at a time, which means 50-100 re fills, also the serial number could be scanned out of the location which would mean another re fill.

I can't think of another way to update the `DataGridView` other than re fill the `TableAdapter`.

Comment: I really wish people would leave a comment for downvoting. Sometimes i get downvoted within seconds of posting a question with no feedback so i just delete the question as i don't want anymore downvotes. If it is a duplicate then at least show me what of. I have googled and search SO without finding a duplicate but of course i could be wrong. i just wish people had to give a reason for downvoting. I wonder sometimes if people do it just to get the badge. It would help so much to leave a comment.

Comment: @DavidWilson _"Questions relating to best practices probably belong on codereview.stackexchange.com."_ This is explicitly stated as off-topic in the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)…

Comment: Thanks. My bad. Although if the OP include their own code, it seems that it would be ok.

Comment: I agree that people should comment on downvotes, but it doesn't seem to be popular practice. Although I haven't downvoted (The question has plenty already <vbg>) It is likely because This kind of question doesn't really belong here. StackOverflow is for problems with specific already written code that isn't working or is behaving unexpectedly that the OP has researched and can't solve. Don't be discouraged though. At the end of the day, rep is not the be all and end all of life ;-)

Comment: So where should i post this question? If not here or codereview? Thank you for your comments i do appreciate them.

Comment: I'm trying to be constructive here so don't take this the wrong way. If you want to prevent getting downvotes, the first thing you should do is read the help center of the site you want to post on. For example: [Stack Overflow's on-topic help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Code Review's on-topic help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Do note each page has links with additional information.

Comment: No problem, after reading the Code Review's on-topic help center i think what i will do is post my code on code review and ask this question there.